# React NewWindow check if window opener was closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's this library:
https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window

I'm trying to add an interval to check if the `window.opener` was closed and if so, close the popup window.
The window is mounted via react `createPortal`, and is kept on the react class as `this.window`.
This is what I've tried:

```
  // Check if window opener was closed
  this.window.window.releaseFunction = function () {
    if (window.opener === null) {
      window.close();
    }
  };

  this.window.window.setInterval(() => {
    this.window.console.log('test');
    this.window.window.releaseFunction();
  }, 200);
```

The `test` gets logged but stops when I close the main window.
What's the problem here? I set the interval on the opened window not on the main one. What can I do?

Comment: You should be able to use the `onUnload` callback function attribute. For security reasons you will not be able to execute `window.close()` from the child window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close